# How to get the command python filename.py to work?

Tags: python, linux

python hello.py in cygdrive isn't working

I've tried this code and it worked: "$ /cygdrive/C/Users/pauls/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe hello.py"

I want to compile a python file in cygdrive by calling it like python

Comment: You need to add the directory containing the `python.exe` into your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: probably relevant: https://superuser.com/q/143119.  cygwin should inherit the `PATH` variable from the system

Answer (score -1):

go into you home directory `cd ~` and open up your `.bashrc` file to add an alias

```
alias python="/cygdrive/C/Users/pauls/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe"
```